# Formula to calculate all values and group them by category

Tags: excel-formula, grouping

I have this table where I wanted to calculate the weighted averages. Items can have different names, but if they have the same code they are used in a weighted average for that code.
[image: Product Table]

I have a working formula `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(B2:B6=B2,C2:C6*D2:D6))` but this specifically works by calculating the values that equal a SPECIFIC code in this case `B2`. How can I restructure this formula so that it automatically calculates and groups each value based on its code. I tried replacing `B2` with `B2:B6` but get an N/A error.

Basically I want a formula that I can select a list of codes and have the weighted averages come up for each one.

Answer (score 0):

In office 365 you could use

```
=LET(data,A2:D6,
     code,INDEX(data,,2),
     weight,INDEX(data,,3),
     cost,INDEX(data,,4),
     unq,UNIQUE(code),
     wa,MMULT(--(unq=TRANSPOSE(code)),weight*cost),
CHOOSE({1,2},unq,wa))
```

This will spill the unique code and it's weight*price result like your sumproduct formula.

[image]